# Fill NA values in data frame from another data frame will preserving existing values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have tried merge and think I am doing something wrong because it the existing values get dropped. 
Here is an example :

```
Data frame 1: 
ID  Color  Size       Shape 
1   red      s        circle
2   NA       s        circle
3   blue     s        circle
4   NA       s        circle

Data frame 2: 
ID   Color 
2    blue
4    green
```

I want this...

```
ID  COLOR       Size       Shape
1   red           s       circle 
2   blue          s       circle
3   blue          s       circle
4   green         s       circle
```

Here Is a sample of my actual data frames.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbUpU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIW6C.png)

I tried this....

```
Dataframe1 <- scalemerge
Dataframe2 <- finding_NA_URIS
colnames(finding_NA_URIS) <- c("track","artist_uri","track_uri","album")
 inx <- is.na(Dataframe1$track_uri)
Dataframe1$track_uri[inx] <- Dataframe2$track_uri[match(Dataframe1$track[inx], Dataframe2$track)]
```

Comment: Just do a `merge` and replace or use `match` i.e. `left_join(df1, df2, by = 'ID") %>% mutate(Color = coalesce(Color.x, Color.y)) %>% select(-Color.x, -Color.y)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun gonna try this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R you can use `match`.

```
inx <- is.na(Dataframe1$Color)
Dataframe1$Color[inx] <- Dataframe2$Color[match(Dataframe1$ID[inx], Dataframe2$ID)]

Dataframe1
#  ID Color Size  Shape
#1  1   red    s circle
#2  2  blue    s circle
#3  3  blue    s circle
#4  4 green    s circle
```

**DATA.**

```
Dataframe1 <- read.table(text = "
ID  Color  Size       Shape 
1   red      s        circle
2   NA       s        circle
3   blue     s        circle
4   NA       s        circle
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


Dataframe2 <- read.table(text = "
ID   Color 
2    blue
4    green
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me and I'm still struggling. I updated my original post with my actual example and what I tried. Maybe there's an error but if you dont mind checkin it out

Comment: @danni.j.t Please don't post data (or code) as images. edit the question with the output of `dput(df)` or, if it's too big, with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))` where `df` is each of your dataframes.

Comment: oh okay thanks! I didn't know that was frowned upon. I wont next time.